# Check if BigDecimal is an integer in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

What is an **efficient** way of determining whether a `BigDecimal` is an integer value in the mathematical sense?

At present I have the following code:

```
private boolean isIntegerValue(BigDecimal bd) {
    boolean ret;
    
    try {
        bd.toBigIntegerExact();
        ret = true;
    } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
        ret = false;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

... but would like to avoid the object creation overhead if possible.

Previously I was using `bd.longValueExact()` which would avoid creating an object if the `BigDecimal` was using its compact representation internally, but obviously would fail if the value was too big to fit into a long.

Comment: Weird - I can see 5 responses on my profile but when I navigate to the question I only see these two.  Is this by design? (i.e. Are response suppressed after I accept an answer?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Depending on the source/usage of your `BigDecimal` values it might be faster to check if the scale <= 0 first. If it is, then it's definitely an integer value in the mathematical sense. If it is >0, then it *could* still be an integer value and the more expensive test would be needed.

Comment: Thanks - Don't know why I didn't think of that, and it's a good optimisation for as this method as I expect the check to pass 99% of the time.

Comment: It doesn't work with (new BigDecimal("0.0")).scale()

Comment: @Sank: did you read the full answer? What you provided is one of those cases where scale alone doesn't give the answer. If you need the full code, feel free to refer to the answer by tobi.

Comment: Yes, tobby's answer is correct

Answer (score 107):

EDIT: As of Java 8, stripTrailingZeroes() now accounts for zero

[BigDecimal stripTrailingZeros doesn't work for zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414785/bigdecimal-striptrailingzeros-doesnt-work-for-zero)

So

```
private boolean isIntegerValue(BigDecimal bd) {
  return bd.stripTrailingZeros().scale() <= 0;
}
```

Is perfectly fine now.

---

If you use the `scale()` and `stripTrailingZeros()` solution mentioned in some of the answers you should pay attention to zero. Zero always is an integer no matter what scale it has, and `stripTrailingZeros()` does not alter the scale of a zero BigDecimal.

So you could do something like this:

```
private boolean isIntegerValue(BigDecimal bd) {
  return bd.signum() == 0 || bd.scale() <= 0 || bd.stripTrailingZeros().scale() <= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Divide the number by 1 and check for a remainder. Any whole number should always have a remainder of 0 when divided by 1.

```
public boolean isWholeNumber(BigDecimal number) {
    return number.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0;
}
```

Comment: It might be worth adding in `number.scale() <= 0 || ...` before calculating the remainder and checking against zero, to avoid unnecessary overhead when the scale indicates it's definitely an integer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this (just summarizing from other answers):

```
private boolean isIntegerValue(BigDecimal bd) {
  return bd.stripTrailingZeros().scale() <= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done the same way that someone would check if a double is an integer, performing % 1 == 0. This is how it would look for a BigDecimal value.

```
public static boolean isIntegerValue(BigDecimal bd){
  return bd.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One possiblity should be to check if [scale()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scale%28%29) is zero or negative. In that case the BigDecimal should have no digits after the decimal point and the number should be a mathematical integer if I understand your question correctly.

**Update**: If positive, it could still be an integer, but you cannot spare extra object creations for further in-depth checks in that case.
An example for such a case is given at the [stripTrailingZeros()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros%28%29) method javadoc (thanks Joachim for the hint in his answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is the cleanest I've come up with.

```
public static boolean isWhole(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
    return bigDecimal.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).compareTo(bigDecimal) == 0;
}
```