# BigDecimal stripTrailingZeros doesn't work for zero

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have met strange bug in my code.

It relates with

```
new BigDecimal("1.2300").stripTrailingZeros()
```

returns `1.23`(correct)

but

```
new BigDecimal("0.0000").stripTrailingZeros()
```

returns `0.0000`(strange), thus nothing happens

Why?

How to fix it?

Comment: I get `0` ... Can you post an MVCE?

Comment: I'm getting `0`, too - JDK 8u66. Which Java version are you running? What do you mean by "returns 0.0000" - do you mean `toString()` prints it as `0.0000`?

Comment: it's a bug fixed in jdk 8 http://stackoverflow.com/a/14772904/1521710

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seems that this is a **bug** ([JDK-6480539](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6480539)) which was fixed in **Java 8** (per OpenJDK commit [2ee772cda1d6](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/2ee772cda1d6)).

Workaround for earlier versions of Java:

```java
BigDecimal zero = BigDecimal.ZERO;
if (someBigDecimal.compareTo(zero) == 0) {
    someBigDecimal = zero;
} else {
    someBigDecimal = someBigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros();
}
```

Comment: Why downvoting? I've faced with similar issues on the older version of jdk. By the way in the answer is direct link to that bug.

Comment: i cannot change jdk version in my project) Is there another way?

Comment: @gstackoverflow When you can't update your JDK version, then you need to perform the fix manually with something like this: `BigDecimal stripped = blub.intValue() == 0 ? BigDecimal.ZERO : blub.stripTrailingZeros();`.

Comment: @JordiCastilla OP is asking about unexpected behaviour of a standard library function, Yuri provides an answer with sources that it's a bug in the standard library. How is that not an answer?

Comment: @JordiCastilla [It would still state, that this is a (fixed) bug.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: @Yuri great workaround, but please [read how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in SO: ***Provide context for links:** Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.* update it and you will get my upvote

Comment: Don’t waste resources creating your own zero instance. Use [`BigDecimal.ZERO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ZERO)

Comment: @Holger Actually that's a good point. Thanks for that, updated and included in the answer.

Comment: You don’t need to structure your answer by putting “UPD #x” sections beneath each other. Those, who are interested in the history, can see it by clicking on the [“edited …” link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34414905/revisions). So don’t hesitate to replace `new BigDecimal("0")` by `BigDecimal.ZERO` in your original code. You don’t need to cite me.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it is fixed in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Javadoc for that method, which certainly suggests that isn't the intended behaviour, but isn't conclusive:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros()

Exactly why it isn't doing this is down to the implementation then.  Which JDK are you using?  For OpenJDK, we can see the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigDecimal.java#BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros%28%29) to figure out how it's reaching this conclusion, but other JDKs may differ.